# Cannot get message through data channel

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am using WebRTC. My audio and video are working well. I try to add a data channel.

I use openDataChannel() function just after ice handling setup and before creating offer.

```
// setup ice handling
this.myConnection.onicecandidate = (ev) => {
    if (ev.candidate) {
        this.send({
            type: 'candidate',
            candidate: ev.candidate
        });
    }
};
this.openDataChannel();
```

// openDataChannel()

```
openDataChannel() {
    let dataChannelOptions = {
        reliable: true
    };
    this.dataChannel = this.myConnection.createDataChannel('myLabel', dataChannelOptions);

    this.dataChannel.onerror = (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    };

    this.dataChannel.onmessage = (ev) => {
        console.log('Got message ', ev.data);
    };

    this.dataChannel.onopen = () => {
        console.log('Data Channel is opened.');
        console.log('this.dataChannel', this.dataChannel);   // Screenshot below
        console.log('this.myConnection', this.myConnection); // Screenshot below
        this.dataChannel.send('Hello!');
    };

    this.dataChannel.onclose = () => {
        console.log('Data Channel is closed.');
    };
}
```

In latest Chrome and Opera, the data channel can open and close correctly. But the other user cannot get message. And no error shows up.

In Firefox, it is weird, the data channel open correctly, but after 7 or 8 seconds, the data channel close automatically (Audio and video are still working).

What can cause this? Thanks

Below is `this.dataChannel` and `this.myConnection`:

[image]

Comment: are you creating the datachannel before creating offer?

Comment: Hi @mido For caller, yes, I created datachannel before creating offer. For callee, I created datachannel just after getting offer. My console can show 'Data Channel is opened.', but just cannot get message

Answer (score 3):

I guess the mistake you are making is creating datachannel in both ends and not accepting either on the other end through `ondatachannel`, and you end up with two dangling datachannels that send message but no one is listening on the other side. Take a look at the example below, works in chrome and firefox:

```js
"use strict";
let pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection()
  , pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection()
  , div = document.getElementById('log')
  , add = (pc, can) => can && pc.addIceCandidate(can).catch(log)
  , log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg
  , exchangeSDP = () => pc1.createOffer().then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
      .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
      .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
      .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
      .catch(log)
  , setChannelEvents = (dataChannel, label) => {
          dataChannel.onerror = log;
          dataChannel.onclose = () => log(`Data Channel is closed: ${label}`);
          dataChannel.onmessage = ev => log(`${label}, Got message:  ${ev.data}`);
          dataChannel.onopen = () => log(`Data Channel is opened: ${label}`);          
          setTimeout(() => dataChannel.send('Hello from '+label), 3000);
      }
  
pc1.onicecandidate = e => add(pc2, e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => add(pc1, e.candidate);
pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => log(pc1.iceConnectionState);
setChannelEvents( pc1.createDataChannel('label', { reliable: true }), 'Peer1');
pc2.ondatachannel = evt => setChannelEvents(evt.channel, 'Peer2');
exchangeSDP();
```

```html
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
<div id='log'></div>
```

P.S: [code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mido22/Lsjv0ub5/), code taken from jib's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35852068/3074768) and modified.

Comment: Thanks, @mido, I think you guess may correct. But in the code, the only thing can make sure one user connect with the other correct user is when using `this.myConnection.createDataChannel`. Am I missing something? (I also added the screenshot of `this.myConnection` in my question, which is same like `pc1` and `pc2` in your code showing in the console.)

Comment: hmm, is there any way I can know whether someone is connected with this user, and who is connected with this user in datachannel?

Comment: wow, it is my mistake, I didn't see clear, `ondatachannel` should not be always `null`! Maybe that is why my code is not running well. I will try to find where the error is. thanks!!